# Types of encryption available in Java?

Tags: java, encryption

I am implementing a data transfer model in Java. I have implemented `DES`, `3DES` and `AES` in my application, and I am interested in knowing if there is any other encryption types that can be included?

Comment: I hope you didn't actually _implement_ those algorithms yourself, they're widely available in existing libraries!

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher for all the algorithms bundled with Java, without even needing to install any security provider.

Comment: Ya I used existing libraries..

Comment: If this is for an application where you give your users a choice of which encryption method to use, you might want to reconsider - Bruce Schneier is of the opinion that users are usually clueless and should be given as few encryption options as possible.

Comment: That was useful.. My application is a research bed so i am planning to implement many as possible.

Answer (score 5):

You can use all of [JCE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html)'s algorithms available to the cryptographic provider in use. For example, [here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html) are some of the algorithms available for [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org), a popular JCE provider.

Answer (score 4):

you could have a look at [bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) - they implement a whole bunch of crypto algorithms for java